# What's the difference between sleep() (unistd.h) and Sleep() (windows.h)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, posix, sleep

Are there any fundamental differences between `windows.h` sleep function and same in `unistd.h`?

Except that `unistd.h` is from POSIX and `windows.h` is Windows native and that `Sleep()` takes milliseconds. Interested in the difference between their internal implementations.

Comment: _"Are there any fundamental differences"_ Yes, `Sleep()` takes millisecond values, while `sleep()` takes seconds.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, thank you. Are there any preferences to use one of them on Windows or they are completely the same?

Comment: The preference is to use [`std::thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: You need a CRT implementation that exposes posix functions on Windows.  Like mingw64, a popular choice.  Which does what they [all do](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/ecb4ff5498dfedd6abcbadb889b84fab19ee57b2/mingw-w64-crt/misc/sleep.c#L12), no difference.